# Filter list of array with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to filter this

`Alert me when this account’s current balance goes above $1.`

from the list here:

```
alertTypes = [
 'Alert me when this account’s available balance goes below $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s current balance goes below $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s available balance goes above $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s current balance goes above $1.']
```

Using this async function

```
const alertRegEx = "/.*current balance.*above.*/"
const alert = alertTypes.filter(alert => alert.match(alertRegEx))
```

But im getting the whole list in *alert* variable. What's my mistake here?

Comment: You regex is not a regex but a string. Try removing the quotes

Comment: Also, why use `async`/`await`? There is no asynchronous code here. Moreover, you cannot use an async function for a `.filter()` predicate.

Comment: I just did a shortcut but basically the regex came from a json. say something like 

{
"test" : {
"testRegex": "/.*current balance.*above.*/"} 
}

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do not use `async` in this case as `match`  is not an async function (*but even if it was you would not be able to use it in a `filter`*). Then you need to use an literal regular expression,not a string.

And a minor, non-required, change is that you can skip the initial and final `.*`

```js
const alertTypes = [
 'Alert me when this account’s available balance goes below $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s current balance goes below $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s available balance goes above $1.',
 'Alert me when this account’s current balance goes above $1.']



const alertRegEx = /current balance.*above/;
const alerts = alertTypes.filter( alert =>  alert.match(alertRegEx))

console.log(alerts);
```

Comment: I just clipped this but basically the regex came from a json file. So I had to add the quotes.

Comment: Then you could create a regular expression out of it by using `const actualRegex = new RegExp(alertRegEx);` but you will need to remove the starting & ending `/`

Comment: I will try this. Do I still use the filter function? or the .test now?